# Lightbox to show videos from Youtube and Vimeo?

Tags: youtube, lightbox, vimeo

I'm looking for a lightbox to show videos from Youtube and Vimeo.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Check recently-released Magnific Popup - http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2013/05/02/truly-responsive-lightbox/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[videobox-lb.sourceforge.net](http://videobox-lb.sourceforge.net/)

Comment: Videobox is a cool project, free and works ok, but it´s too outdated and the window is a little ugly. Good for a school project, but very far from a professional solution.

Answer (score 14):

Check out [Fancybox](http://fancybox.net).  If you need the video to autoplay this example [site](http://webdesignandsuch.com/posts/fancybox-youtube) was helpful!

Comment: Fancybox 2.0 is now available here: http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/

Comment: Just FYI, Fancybox is commercial.

Comment: Fancybox is now licensed under "Creative Commons Attribution-NonCommercial 3.0". It cannot be used for commercial purposes and must include a link to the author.

Comment: You just have to pay a small fee to use it commercially ($19 for one domain, $89 for many):
"fancyBox licensed under Creative Commons Attribution-NonCommercial 3.0 license. 
You are free to use fancyBox for your personal or non-profit website projects. 
You can get the author's permission to use fancyBox for commercial websites by paying a fee."

http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/#license

Answer (score 8):

I like [prettyPhoto](http://www.no-margin-for-errors.com/projects/prettyphoto-jquery-lightbox-clone/), IMHO it's the one that looks the best.

Comment: Agreed. Pretty photo is awesome.

Comment: Doesn't work well at all on mobile though. Looking for a replacement at the moment.

Answer (score 7):

[Shadowbox](http://www.shadowbox-js.com/) is your best choice. Check it out.

Comment: Shadowbox is commercial. The better looking (and easier to use) alternative [Fancybox](http://fancybox.net/) is licensed under MIT.

Comment: I don't recommend Shadowbox EVER, it doesn't work well with youtube videos and it doesn't work on ipad devices, and that is a growing platform :(

Comment: I agree - Shadowbox is by far the easiest to setup and comprehend for quick/simple setup. ~5 lines of code and a couple words added to an <a href=''> link and your popup is appearing. No fuss whatsoever. I tried Fancybox - way too complicated.

Comment: @enyo, if you use Fancybox on commercial website you need to purchase a license: http://sites.fastspring.com/fancyapps/product/store

Comment: shadowbox-js.com isn't opening

Answer (score 1):

Check out [this list](https://web.archive.org/web/20120422035501/http://blog.insicdesigns.com/2009/01/10-promising-jquery-lighbox-plugin) of lightbox plugins, depending on your exact requirements you can find the plugin of your choice from there easier than asking here. If you need a specific lightbox which can do just about anything and everything, try [NyroModal](http://nyromodal.nyrodev.com/).

Answer (score 1):

I've had a LOT of trouble with pretty photo and IE9.  I also had issues with fancybox in IE.

For youtube.com, I'm having a lot of luck with CeeBox.

http://catcubed.com/2008/12/23/ceebox-a-thickboxvideobox-mashup/

Comment: Your link doesn't work. This link works: http://www.colinaut.com/2008/12/23/ceebox-a-thickboxvideobox-mashup/